# GPO config problems

Tags: group-policy

I'm administrating an ou.
And I have applied a rule for screen saver lockout. Some OU's under my OU have applied the settings and some haven't..., What can be the cause of this?

Is there a way to check applied settings on a specific machine?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was in the scope settings of the GPO, my users under the OU wheren't configured there.

@Trondh is a very nice tool you can run on your users machine to see the result accumulation of all policy's for this user and machine.

Answer (score 3):

Some OUs may have 'block inheritence' configured, which will prevent higher GPOs from being applied. On the face of it, this seems the most likely cause. You can find the setting under Group Policy Management, as shown here:

[image: GP Block Inheritence]

You should be able to evaluate the Resultant Set of Policy for particular user/computer combinations by using the tools provided in the Group Policy Management MMC console. There's more information on this here:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc781242%28WS.10%29.aspx

This is where you find the wizard you need:

[image: GP Modeling Wizard]

Answer (score 1):

My tool of choice for checking applied GPOs is rsop.msc. - it's included on windows xp and newer. Just run rsop.msc from the command line on the computer/user you wish to check, and it will give you all applied settings/GPOs.